# $state.go is also calling its parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
$stateProvider
  .state("home", {
    url: "/home",
    templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
    controller: "homeCtrl"
  })
  .state("home.abc", {
    url: "/abc/:id",
    templateUrl: "templates/abc.html",
    controller: "abcCtrl"
  })
  .state("home.abc.xyz", {
    url: "/xyz",
    templateUrl: "templates/xyz.html",
    controller: "xyzCtrl"
  })
  .controller('abctrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $state.go('home.abc.xyz', {
      'id': $stateParams.id
    });
  })
```

-----after state is going to home.abc.xyz its again finally going back to home state. Please let me know who it resolve this ?

Comment: Please share the code of `xyzCtrl`.

Comment: why have a state that re-directs to another state?

Comment: we are adding some HTMLs inside xyzCtrl. But after this execution state.go('home.abc.xyz', {
      'id': $stateParams.id
    }); Its agian going back to parent state home

Comment: As per requirement it has to go from one state to another

Comment: you do not have any parameters defined under `home.abc.xyz` state.

Comment: Can you please put the code as to how it should be written

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
//...
.state("home.abc.xyz", {
    url: "/xyz",
    templateUrl: "templates/xyz.html",
    controller: "xyzCtrl",
    params:{
       id: null
    }
  })
```

**EDIT:**

I took me a while to understand what is the problem, bellow is the solution. Simply, there is nothing wrong with `ui.router`, however, your configuration is wrong. Let me try to explain.

When you requested your `xyz` state, `ui.router` fist loaded home template, and then it tried to load `abc` template inside of `home` and at the end `xyz` into `abc`. Since you probably do not have correct HTML in templates (as I made in the code bellow) `ui.router` is loading only `home` template since it knows where to put it. I hope you understand the problem and solution here.

```
$stateProvider
  .state("home", {
    url: "/home",
    templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
    controller: "homeCtrl"
  })
  .state("home.abc", {
    url: "/abc/:id",
    views:{
        'abc': {
            templateUrl: "templates/abc.html",
            controller: "abcCtrl"
        }
    }
  })
  .state("home.abc.xyz", {
    url: "/xyz",
    views:{
        'xyz': {
            templateUrl: "templates/xyz.html",
            controller: "xyzCtrl"
        }
    }

  })
  .controller('abctrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
    //this should not be part of any controller.
    /*$state.go('home.abc.xyz', {
      'id': $stateParams.id
    });*/
  })
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <div ui-view></div>
<body>
```

**home.html**

```
<div ui-view="abc"></div>
```

**abc.html**

```
<div ui-view="xyz"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this, but still it went back to home controller

Comment: any idea how to fix this issue ?

Comment: can you please make `home.abc.xyz` child of `home` and not `home.abc` so at the end to be `home.xyz` and use it with `$state.go('home.xyz')`

Comment: No it wont work i tried, State.go to any child state is finally reloading parent state

Comment: I tried your named ui-view solution, but it did not work. Still home ctrl is getting executed on  $state.go('home.abc.xyz', {
      'id': $stateParams.id
    });                                                                                                                  statechange is called like this from home.html                                      ui-sref=".abc({id:data.id})"

Comment: As i said before, of course it is going to be executed, if you want it not to be executed, you have to delete it from state, so it will never be resolved. And tell me again, why you have controllers that's only job to redirect to another page? if you want a help, you need to post all your code. only way to make what you want is to make every state independent of other one. make them all level one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.

Finally this solution worked.

app.run(function($rootScope, $location, $state, $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){

```
        if(toState.name == "home.abc") {

            $state.go('home.abc.xyz', {'id': toParams.id});

        }
    });
})
```